# node http.get() -- how do I get at the XML returned so I can do stuff with it?

Tags: xml, node.js, http, request, buffer

I am trying to make an HTTP GET request to an XML API, wait for the returned XML string, and convert it into a JS object and eventually to JSON. The xml2js module should work fine for the end of that process, but I'm trying to use node's native http.request / http.get methods to make the request, and I don't understand how it works exactly even after reading the docs several times.

Here's a gist of what I'm trying to do, and how I'm receiving a whole lot of  etc that I don't know how to parse.

https://gist.github.com/jasonrhodes/6942015

How does the http.get() method work in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are using version *0.10.**. What happens is that HTTP can send requests in *chunks*, which means the response may come in many different pieces.

You should have a String object and concatenate the *chunks* as you receive them to this object, after there are no more *chunks* a **end** event is emitted by the response object.

The code follows:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var options = {
        hostname: "search.mysite.com",
        path: '/search?site=hub&client=hub_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&q=cats'
    };

    var gsaReq = http.get(options, function (response) {
        var completeResponse = '';
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            completeResponse += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function() {
            console.log(completeResponse);
        })
    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

});

app.listen(3000);
```